# VScode python context color theme - modify the color of modules and methods

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, colors

I wish to modify the text color of **modules**, class **methods** and **constants** (but not of simple variables, if possible).
I use the "One Dark Pro" theme for VScode (see the picture with example below)

In this example I wish to modify

- the "np" at "np.arange..." to red (or other custom color)
- the "shape" to blue, as the "arange" method name
- the x at "x.shape" should keep its color, as it is not a module name

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding these to your settings.json file (tweak colors and styles to your taste, I just made them blunt for you to see)

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[One Dark Pro]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "name": "Python - Your description",
                "scope": [
                    "entity.name.namespace"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff0000",
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Python - Your description",
                "scope": [
                    "meta.attribute.python"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#0066ff",
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: "meta.attribute.python" works great, don't see any difference with "entity.name.namespace"

Comment: It’s not very encouraging to keep helping if you don’t give the bit that helped a thumbs up.

Answer (score 2):

Due to "[Editor semantic highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-semantic-highlighting)", when using other theme extensions, sometimes it will be ignored, and when I use VS Code theme "Dark+(default dark)", it is displayed:

[image]

[image]

As for the colors of "arrange" and "shape", because they are not methods defined in the module "numpy" document, the language service cannot recognize them as methods and display colors. For example, when we use "`z = np.array`", it displays the color:

[image]

More reference: [Customizing a Color Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme).

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add the code for these settings?

Comment: @Alexander -For this color theme, I just selected "Dark+(default dark)" (as in the screenshot 1 in my answer). You could also click _F1_, then enter "_Preferences: Color Theme_", select " Dark+(default dark)".

Comment: Mine looks different, np still wo color. Thanks for the reference, I found it useful.

Comment: @Alexander  -It is recommended that you try to comment out the relevant code color settings and disable the theme extensions that you do not use. If you have any questions about this thread, please let me know. If my answer solves this problem, please [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to help others who have the same problem.

Comment: @Alexander -How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.